how to create complex polar area chart
Refer this image  I have a reference image that I want to recreate in my project, but I haven't found anything similar. The closest matches I found are Highcharts and D3.js charts. The chart I'm working on involves categories and subcategories, and I'm having trouble mapping these. Additionally, the categories are divided into two main groups. Could you help me with this?
can you please help me to create this complex chart. thanks in advance..
